# brunch polymer starter kit configuration

Tags: polymer, brunch

Someone can help me to get a brunch configuration working with polymer 2.0 starter kit and it's bower_components dependencies ?

I would like to get a running server with brunch (with browser-sync and fb-flo ....) intead of 'polymer serve'.

i tried a lot of brunch-config.coffee but can't copy '/index.html' into public

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried the docs?

Comment: I'm now using a fb-flo server and polymer serve both together !